# Enable & Control mouse cursor on android

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am searching for a way to enable the mouse cursor on android and control the movements via code. The same as when you plug in a mouse via USB-OTG - but without doing it. Is there any API or other way to do that?

Comment: This is not possible from the Android SDK. There may be ways for rooted devices to do it, and it is certainly possible if you modify your own copy of the OS.

Comment: just one thought for doing it without modifying the OS - could I run a Bluetooth HID via the android device and connect to the same device to do what I want with a stock android device?

Comment: I hope not, as that would be a serious security hole.

Comment: why? There could be some user-interaction/confirmation involved and after thinking a bit more about it - it should be possible as it is possible between different devices - why not on the same one?

Comment: "why?" -- allowing one app to control the UI of another is generally a security problem. "why not on the same one?" -- I doubt that a Bluetooth radio can connect to itself.

Comment: seems to be possible with the Android SDK: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.skm

Comment: Well, then, that's another security hole that I need to get fixed. Thank you for pointing this out!